# Difference between car-like and skid-steer robot?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the base_local_planner package with the holonomic flag set to false.

However, I want to know if there will be any difference in performance between a car like robot and a skid steer robot? If yes, then what care do we need to take to switch between the two.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192195/difference-between-car-like-and-skid-steer-robot?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2014-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ackermann (car-like) robots pose very different navigation challenges from a traditional diff drive or holonomic robot.

The [Ackermann SIG](http://wiki.ros.org/Ackermann%20Group) is a very loose collection of ROS users working with ackermann-type robots.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0